# Editing a past commit message

Tags: git

I spelled some words wrong in a past commit message and want to fix them.
They were not from the last commit (5 commits ago) so `--amend` doesn't work here.

What would be the easiest way to fix this mistake?

Comment: You could use this tool: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch (it's quite hard to handle, so I would recommend looking for a tutorial - many of them can be found at the GitHub help site)

Comment: You should rebase to old commt and then modify the it.

Comment: git rebase -i HEAD~5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Identify the commit you want to change with `git log --oneline`.

```
$ git log --oneline
5ebe0d0 foo
66096c8 bar
d83d7a7 *typo*
a9f4c59 baz
...
```

Then do an interactive rebase onto the parent of that commit (identified with the `^`).

```
$ git rebase --interactive 'd83d7a7^'
```

This should fire up the default editor – which, unless you've changed it, is vim.

---

(This is for those less comfortable with vim.)

Press <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> and type the word `edit`. Press <kbd>esc</kbd> and type `:wq` to save and quit the file.

---

Now all you have to do is `git commit --amend`, and you'll be prompted to edit your commit message. Then finish the rebase with `git rebase --continue`.

**NOTE: if you have any merge history, this will flatten it.** If you really don't want this, use the `--preserve-merges` option with `git rebase` (as well as `--interactive`).

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for!